# MYSQLI Search Query crashes GoDaddy Site server

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, search, mysqli

Im having a problem with my search query, after typing in searches several times the site just crashes, I'm not sure if it is due to a lack of RAM I payed for at GoDaddy or if my search query is throwing an error or demanding too much resources.

Please could you test the search here : http://cameras.specced.co.uk

Please type in several different cameras models and do this several times, the search query will then stop working and the site will no longer work.

Here is the search query:

```
$model_search_query = $cameras_pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM models WHERE concat_ws(' ',brand_name,model) LIKE :search LIMIT 5");
$model_search_query->execute(array(':search' => "%" . $_POST['search'] . "%"));

while ($model_search = $model_search_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $brand_search_query = "SELECT brand FROM brands WHERE id =" . $model_search['brand']; 
    $brand_search = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($cameras, $brand_search_query)); ?>

        <a href="compare.php?compare_1=<?php echo $model_search['id'];?>">



        <div class="search_result">
            <div class="search_result_image">
                <!--  IMAGE REMOVED TO TEST IF THIS WAS CAUSING THE ISSUE -->
            </div>

            <div class="search_result_text">
                <?php echo $brand_search['brand'] . " " . $model_search['model']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
 <?php } ?>
```

I have removed the image from the search results just incase it was too large and too many being loaded at the same time in the drop down search caused the issue, however the website still crashes after searching only a few times.

This is the error I receive in Safari,

Safari cannot open.... because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection...

Thankyou for any help

EDIT:

Here is the entire contents of my fetch.php that is included in by AJAX when the user searches on the top right search bar in the header at http://cameras.specced.co.uk

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ?>

<!-- REQUIRE DB -->
<?php 
    $servername = "xxx";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";
    $dbname = "xxx";
?>
<?php
    $cameras = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $cameras_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'); 
?>


<?php 


    $model_search_query = $cameras_pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM models WHERE concat_ws(' ',brand_name,model) LIKE :search LIMIT 5");
    $model_search_query->execute(array(':search' => "%" . $_POST['search'] . "%"));

    while ($model_search = $model_search_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $brand_search_query = "SELECT brand FROM brands WHERE id =" . $model_search['brand']; 
        $brand_search = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($cameras, $brand_search_query));
p?1=' . $_POST['current'] . "&2=" . $model_search['id'] . '">'; 

            echo '<a href="compare.php?compare_1=' . $model_search['id'] . '">'. 

            '<div class="search_result">' .
                '<div class="search_result_image">' .
                    '<img src="http://www.specced.co.uk/images/cameras/[' . $model_search['id'] . ']_front.png">' .
                '</div>' .

                '<div class="search_result_text">' .
                    $brand_search['brand'] . " " . $model_search['model'] . 
                '</div>' .
            '</div>' .
        '</a>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Any one, I would love to get this sorted

Answer (score 0):

When the site stops responding, if you check the developer console in your browser Network panel and check the response from fetch.php, you'll see that the last HTTP 200 response only contains the following:

```
<!-- REQUIRE DB -->
```

The subsequent request are blank. Therefore, I'm guessing that PHP dies when it tries to make your DB connection. Check your error_log and post your error here as a comment! Do you close your DB connection when you are finished?

Comment: I've also noticed if you wait a while, it starts working again, so its as if your max connections limit is reached with your DB. Maybe worth investigating.

Comment: Hi, No I don't close the db connection, the code I added in my question is a separate php file included by Ajax, at the top is a opening PDO connection, however I do not close the connection at the bottom of the file... I didn't thing this was necessary ?

Comment: Usually it isn't, but it might be worthwhile to do so in this case.

Comment: Yes I noticed this, it comes back up after around 1 min, do you mean check developer log in browser or in the go daddy hosting ?

Comment: urgh, just googled, and they dont let you access the error_log, wth? https://be.godaddy.com/community/Building-and-Managing-a-Website/PHP-error-logs-for-my-account/td-p/10283

Comment: you'd need to add ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); then in fetch.php instead

Comment: I have just turned error reporting on as you said, and also added die(); at the bottom of fetch.php however the die(); doesn't seem to have solved anything

Comment: Now you are getting `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function close() on null in <b>/home/cousbrad/public_html/cameras/sections/fetch.php</b> on line <b>89</b><br />`

Comment: So you are not getting your connection and therefore can't close it

Comment: I  added $cameras->mysqli->close(); to try and close the connection a different way however this throws that error, so I will remove it

Comment: Its odd as the search works perfectly for 3-5 times and then stops working as you said, after this the site goes down for about a min

Comment: It seems to happen only if you type in two words, say canon 700d or canon Eos 700d